# Remove OTA downloaded (but not installed) iOS 8

Tags: software-update, iphone, ios

I've downloaded the new iOS 8 update on my iPhone 5 but am getting second thoughts about actually installing it.  Is there a way for me to delete that download or am I at the point of no return?

Answer (score 16):

I did same on iPad2.  I have managed to remove the download (which wasn't installed).  Select settings, general, usage, manage storage when the app list loads, you should see ios8, select this and then delete. Hope you're successful.

Comment: Settings | General | Usage (Not Software Update). Then in the list of apps the downloaded ios8 is shown and you are able to delete!

Comment: Cheryl, that was so darn easy--thanks it worked perfectly.  In reference to Tetsujin, it won't download again unless you go into "settings>software update>and prompt it to update. I'm going to wait it out for two reasons--Yosemite won't launch until next month (Oct) and iOS8 isn't backward compatible with Mavericks, and also to give them time to iron out the wrinkles.

Comment: For a few of the first responders keep in mind I downloaded it but did not prompt it to install so basically the update was sitting in my phone waiting for install. I am very aware that once you install unless it's a Beta version you can't go back:)  Thanks again Cheryl--good move.

Comment: iOS 8 on my iPhone 5 is synching without issue whatsoever on OS X Lion 10.7.5. Mavericks would pose no issue whatsoever. As for "won't download unless", iOS automatically downloads any time it finds them. Generally, iOS checks once a week.

Comment: @Trane Whilst true, it seems that doing this prevents iOS's normal update checking—no requests are being made to the servers ([ref](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108314/how-can-i-prevent-ios-7-from-downloading-to-ios-6-devices))

Comment: Even after a week, @grgarside? I would be surprised if this cancels out iOS's normal checks for updates.

Comment: @Trane I'm not seeing any network traffic to the aforementioned servers and the update hasn't downloaded again, and neither have I been prompted to update.

Comment: @grgarside: Fair enough, but I cannot believe that this is a permanent thing. If so, it means that software update has effectively been broken merely by deleting a download. That's not a feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop and delete the update of iOS 8 by going to Settings/Usage and selecting the iOS 8 app which will give you the option to delete and it won't auto-download unless you decide to do so by going in the software update option.

Comment: Kenpachi is correct. iOS7 allows you to delete the update package if it has downloaded to your iPhone. However, Apple insists on notifying you immediately of the availability of the iOS 8 update, which means you permanently have a "1" by the Settings icon. Is there a way of blocking this notification, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to delete downloaded iOS updates.

Settings | General | Software Update does not feature a delete button. On a non-jailbroken iPhone, once an iOS update has been downloaded (manually or otherwise), there is no permanent means of deletion.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4483117

[How to delete downloaded iOS 6 update?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66925/how-to-delete-downloaded-ios-6-update)

[How to delete the iOS7 install package on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/how-to-delete-the-ios7-install-package-on-iphone)

This scenario plays itself out during every major release.

Comment: source please !

Comment: Settings | General | Software Update does not feature a delete button. On a non-jailbroken iPhone, once an iOS update has been downloaded (manually or otherwise), there is no permanent means of deletion.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4483117
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66925/how-to-delete-downloaded-ios-6-update
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104318/how-to-delete-the-ios7-install-package-on-iphone

This scenario plays itself out during every major release.

Comment: Nice, now just copy paste that in your answer please.

Comment: Later versions of iOS allow you to delete the downloaded update if you're not jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

Just deleted ios8 update from settings: general: usage: storage (see all apps). ios8 is the largest "app" and will be the first choice.